# iOS app crashing, Unable to find scenario

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging

When running my app, it crashes and I don't see something wrong with my code. Please help me to find this issue.

Here is the code in method `didSelectRow` in `UITableViewDelegate`, where it crashes:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[[SingletonClass SharedMethod] setGlobalAddSubjectResueIdentifier:@"ForListDetails"];
[self.tblSearchHolder deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tblSearchHolder indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];

NSDictionary *dictGGetSelectedVal=[arrLoadDataTemp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[[SingletonClass SharedMethod] setGlobalSelectedSearchProperty:dictGGetSelectedVal];

arrGetValForTable=nil;
arrLoadDataTemp=nil;

[[SingletonClass SharedMethod] setGlobalHolder:@"addPropertyScene"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ChangeViewsAsPerCriteria" object:nil];
```

}

And the crash report itself:

> NSInvalidArgumentException: Cannot create task from nil request

```
18  UIKit  0x18d7f8b20 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] (in UIKit) + 1352 
19  UIKit                               0x18d8a1760 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] (in UIKit) + 268
20  UIKit                               0x18d94faa8 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks (in UIKit) + 292
21  UIKit                               0x18d942e5c _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks (in UIKit) + 288
22  UIKit                               0x18d6d4464 _afterCACommitHandler (in UIKit) + 132
23  CoreFoundation                      0x1840cecdc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation) + 32
24  CoreFoundation                      0x1840cc694 __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation) + 412
25  CoreFoundation                      0x1840ccc50 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 1292
26  CoreFoundation                      0x183fecc58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 436
27  GraphicsServices                    0x185e98f84 GSEventRunModal (in GraphicsServices) + 100
28  UIKit                               0x18d7455c4 UIApplicationMain (in UIKit) + 236
29  EnrichedValues                      0x100dd6cc8 0x100d80000 + 355528
30  libdyld.dylib                       0x183b0c56c start (in libdyld.dylib) + 4
```

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: I updated my question..@MilanNosáľ

Comment: [self.tblSearchHolder deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tblSearchHolder indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];

try 

[self.tblSearchHolder deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath  animated:YES];

Comment: ChangeViewsAsPerCriteria is not a method@PPL

Comment: problem is in this line `[self.tblSearchHolder indexPathForSelectedRow]`

Comment: ChangeViewsAsPerCriteria is the notification name, which method called by posting this notification, is that method accepts arguments?

Comment: The accept arguments is..
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeViewScenes) name:@"ChangeViewsAsPerCriteria" object:nil];
-(void)changeViewScenes
{
    NSString *sceneToDisplay=[[SingletonClass SharedMethod] globalHolder];
    [self loadStatusView:sceneToDisplay];
}
.@PPL

Comment: Same problem after change this line [self.tblSearchHolder indexPathForSelectedRow]..@Anbu.karthik

Comment: When your didSelect fires, are you triggering some network activity?  Because that exception's error message comes from the networking stack.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it can be found quite easily (with a bit of luck :)).

1. First of all, try to enable NSZombie objects as follows:

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]

2. Try to put an exception breakpoint as follows (make sure you're on the breakpoint's tab):

[image: Step 3]

Good luck & happy coding! :)